# Sublime Text 3 Settings file "Preferences.sublime-settings" auto order by alphabetically?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

**Before**
[image]
**After**
[image]

Before:

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2,
"font_face": "microsoft yahei",
"font_size": 11,
```

After

```
"font_face": "microsoft yahei",
"font_size": 11,
"line_padding_bottom": 2,
"line_padding_top": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

After the file is saved auto order by alphabetically.

why?

Comment: you probably have a plugin installed which is doing this

Comment: @KeithHall : You don't experience that? I've wondered the same thing, and it only happens to the main `Preferences.sublime-settings` file. All of my plugin-specific preferences can be formatted arbitrarily with whitespace & comments, but the primary one gets stripped of anything extraneous & alphabetized.

Comment: @Enteleform nope, I don't experience that in `Preferences.sublime-settings` ;)

Comment: possibly related, though for ST2: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bug-comments-deleted-in-preferences-user/7064

Comment: at what point does the file get sorted and the comments stripped? saving it? opening it?

Comment: @KeithHall : Just tested after reading the thread you linked to & can confirm that it happens when SublimeText or a plugin alters the main preferences.  For example, `Preferences > Color Scheme > Color Scheme - Default > Monokai` will overwrite my `color_scheme` value with the path to `monokai`, at which point all comments & whitespace are stripped and all keys are alphabetized.  Pretty much exactly what [**FacelessUser mentioned in that thread**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bug-comments-deleted-in-preferences-user/7064/3).

Comment: @Enteleform yeah, same for me too. So I guess it's non-fixable, but can be worked around by only ever manually changing settings... plugins shouldn't change the main preferences, they should have their own file - which plugins are doing this?

Comment: @KeithHall : Not tested since I haven't used them since I built my personal color scheme + theme; but I'm guessing plugins like [**Themr**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Themr) & [**ColorSchemeSelector**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorSchemeSelector). Seems like they would kind of have to access the main prefs though for what they do. Not sure of any other plugins that might need similar access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110240/discussion-between-keith-hall-and-enteleform).

Answer (score 1):

## Reason

This behavior occurs when Sublime Text or a plugin alters the main preferences file.  For example, changing a color scheme via the `Preferences > Color Scheme` menu will cause this.

[This has been reported on the forums for ST2](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bug-comments-deleted-in-preferences-user/7064/3), but still affects ST3.

Basically it happens because JSON does not have support for comments in the specification. ST allows them because it is stripping them before pulling them into a structure.  Therefore, when preferences are altered by a plugin or ST itself (i.e. not edited by hand), whatever is in the file is disregarded and the structure is just dumped back to the file in alphabetical order.

## Avoidance

This can be avoided by only ever manually changing the preferences file. i.e. not using the menu and not installing any plugins which will modify it...

## Workaround

To work around the comments disappearing, don't use comments! If you want to put a note next to the `tab_size` setting for example, write it as a value for key `tab_size_comment`. That way, when the file is sorted, the note will stay near the relevant setting, and it won't be stripped because it is a proper key-value pair, and not a comment.  Usually, there is no effect of setting an unknown key.

Example:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"tab_size_comment": "some description about tab_size"
```